# Condition based column selection from left join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL query which is straight forward. The only thing I need to do here is if table3 has any matching record then I need select Y else select N. How can I achieve that in SQL Server?

This is my attempt, but I don't think it will work. I'm yet to try it though

```
Select tbl1.col1,
       tbl1.col2,
       tbl2.col1,
       Case When tbl3.count > 0 Then Y Else N End
From table1 tbl1
Inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id
Left join table3 tbl3 on tbl3.Id = tbl1.Id
```

Comment: Your case expression needs an END at its end.

Comment: What isn't working about the above attempt (apart from the syntax error)?

Comment: i have just written a pseudo code. i don think the above one will work. Could you please get me the actual query.

Comment: *"I don think the above one will work."* WHy not? Why don't you try and find out?

Comment: What do you mean, `tbl3.count` ? Is `count` a real column in  `tbl3`?

Comment: It appears you meant to put "left join" instead of "inner join" in the title of your post.

Comment: nope as i said its a pseudo code, count is not a column i wrote this to make you understand the requirement.

Comment: Then, rather than writing pseudo code, why don't you actually try your attempt? If you don't think it will work *why* don't you think it will work? Obviously you know that your table `table3` doesn't have a column `count`, so what difficulty are you having solving the error (`Invalid column name 'count'.`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `case when exists` for such task

```sql
Select tbl1.col1,
       tbl1.col2,
       tbl2.col1,
       CASE When exists (select 1 from table3 tbl3 where tbl3.Id = tbl1.Id) then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END table3_exists
From table1 tbl1
Inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id
```

Comment: Its working perfectly, thanks for quickly understanding my requirement and providing the answer.

Comment: left join was giving duplicates, but the above one is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to check for null instead of count. That is the only thing that sticks out.

```
Select tbl1.col1,
       tbl1.col2,
       tbl2.col1,
       CASE When tbl3.id IS NULL then 'No Value' ELSE 'Has Value' END AS CalcField
From table1 tbl1
Inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id
Left join table3 tbl3 on tbl3.Id = tbl1.Id
```

Comment: This will duplicate rows, if `table3` has multiple references to `table1`.

Comment: @markalex - It will not necessarily return duplicate rows. It will return rows which contain the same id. There is nothing in the question where the omission of multiple records matching the join predicate is required.

Comment: Sure, I don't say this is incorrect, I just point out that this query will produce duplicate rows if there are multiple dependent items in `table3`.

Comment: yes i need to ommit the duplicate rows, because i have multiple dependent items in table3.